# Update recursive items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a list with this this structure:

Id,Title ,Weight,ParentId

that parentId reference to Item in this list.
I want to update all parents "Weight" fields when a child "Wieght" field changed by workflow.

Is there any Idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set option as Workflow start when item Updated then add 
Update Item workflow action.

Click on thislist it will open as Popup

set **List :  Parent List**

Then Click on **Add**

Set This **Filed - Weight**

To this **value - CurrentItem - Weight**

Click on **OK**

Section - Find the List Item

**Field  - ParentitemID**

**Value  - CurrentItem - ParentitemID**

Click on **Ok** then popup came out with warning, just ignore and click on **yes**

finally  **save** and **publish** the workflow.

let me know anything you face difficult to configure designer workflow.